# Mixpanel is not supported for cocos2d-x?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, mixpanel

I have to port game from Cocos2d to Cocos2d-x and in Cocos2d was used Mixpanel for data/event tracking. I looked on Mixpanel official site and they officially do not support c++. Is there any plugin/class for c++ sending events to mixpanel or I have to use REST API ?

Answer (score 0):

Mixpanel has native iOS and android SDKs. For iOS you can call objective-c code from c++ and for android you have JNI to call Java from c++. You dont need to make an REST calls.That is how I have done it for all native SDKs.